# How can I fix this weird mesh up?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I have a mesh with a armature that haven't reacted to the armature properly. The right side of the mesh (dog) seem to be intersected with the left side. How can I fix this in a easy way?
[image]

[image]

Comment: By weightpainting - There is unfortuantely not enough information to give a better advice. When the bone in question is an IK handler bone, then you could have a look if you can remove the vertex group for it completely for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty much a noob, but I need to figure this out in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mirror modifier in your mesh. Apply it, delete your armature modifier and reconnect your armature to your mesh with automatic weights. Oh, and it's best to use subdivision surface modifier after armature modifier, not before it.

Comment: Mirror modifer is applied. I did reconnect my armature to my mesh with automatic weights, but for some reason the right side of the mesh keeps connecting to the left side of the armature. Subsivision surface modifier is now under the armature modifier.

Comment: Did you delete the armature modifier first, before reconnectiing? I tried the steps I provided again with your blend file, and it worked. I could move each leg independently. Btw, you could improve your rig by proper parenting of severeal bones, if you don't mind me mention it. Oh, and you can reset your armature in pose mode by pressing Alt+R, Alt+G and Alt+S (for Rotation, Location and Scale). Best to do that before connecting to your mesh.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to update this. Umm, I got it figured out. I had already made another armature with proper parenting of several bones earlier. Thank you for the extra information. I didn't know about the Alt+, Alt+G, and ALlt+S.